# How to return Docker Compose container to its initial state on stop?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I use a Docker Compose container for integration tests in my app. It contains a Postgres instance inside, with which I communicate from the app.

When I run `docker-compose up`, it starts properly.
Now, when I run `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose stop`, is it possible to clean all changes that were applied during testing process without having to remove and rebuild images?

Comment: Are you talking about changes in Postgres? Are you mounting any volume to the container that runs Postgres?

Comment: if you are using gitlab-ci you can for example build image in one stage and in stage "test" run your tests in paralel, or there is this option "before_test" in gitlab-ci

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `docker-compose down`'s options: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

You can use the option `-v, --volumes` to remove all the volumes used by the services that you spinned up.